# Как прочитать и записать файл txt в python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.x

При запуске данного кода на питоне 2.7

```
with open("counter.txt", "w+") as opening:
start_count_read = opening.read()
print start_count_read
print "\n"
plussing = int(start_count_read) + int(data.count("\n"))
start_count_write = opening.write(str(plussing))
print plussing
```

Результат не тот, который нужен 
Код записывает, но не читается.

Comment: `Код записывает, но не читается` == `"w+"`, все логично

Comment: Да, w+ это значит и писать и читать

Comment: это значит перезаписывать, читать `"r"`, от слова read

Comment: <<w+ Открывает файл для чтения и записи. Указатель стоит в начале файла. Создает файл с именем имя_файла, если такового не существует.>> Это документация

Comment: Меня интересует вопрос, а как при открытии можно сделать чтобы и работал и write и read

Answer (score 2):

При использовании `mode='w+'`, Python первым делом обрежет файл до нулевой длины (причем уже при открытии) и вернет `file object` указывающий на **пустой** файл.

Небольшая демонстрация:

создаем новый файл и пишем в него 100 символов `'X'`:

```
In [63]: open('d:/temp/test.txt', 'w').write('X' * 100)
Out[63]: 100
```

проверяем

```
In [64]: open('d:/temp/test.txt', 'r').read()
Out[64]: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

пытаемся просто открыть тот же файл в режиме `'w+'`:

```
In [65]: open('d:/temp/test.txt', 'w+')
Out[65]: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='d:/temp/test.txt' mode='w+' encoding='cp1251'>
```

и снова перечитать его, но уже в режиме чтения `'r'`, т.е. повторяем шаг (64):

```
In [66]: open('d:/temp/test.txt', 'r').read()
Out[66]: ''
```

Файл пустой! Он был обнулен на шаге (65).

---

Вы можете использовать `mode='a+'` (`append`):

```
with open("counter.txt", "a+") as f:
    # перевести текущую позицию в начало файла
    # для open(..., mode='a+') указатель будет в конце файла
    f.seek(0)
    # прочитать все содержимое файла (указатель окажется в конце файла)
    data = f.read()
    # ...
    # записать `new_data` в текущую позицию в файле
    f.write(new_data)
```